# TypeError: record.factory is not a function in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

While running the ionic serve command, Getting the following error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to comment

`@Injectable()` in your routing or injecting else

Example

```
//   @Injectable()  comment this code

 @NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule],
providers: [] 
 })
```